# Jeet Framework: Got an error when trying to run Jeet 2:

Tags: css-frameworks

Got an error when trying to run Jeet 2:

In CMD:
Compiling Stylus OK!
Saving Compiled Stylus OK!

Live Reload is on and listening!

Compiling SCSS ... Error!

I'm on Windows XP

Is there something with the Ruby installation on Windows?
I followed your tutorial on https://github.com/CorySimmons/jeet#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

If you can type `ruby` into your Command Prompt and it doesn't return an error then you have Ruby.

You need to install Compass as well: http://compass-style.org/install/

Answer (score 0):

In Windows command prompt you don't use the $ in front of the gem command! You just type gem update system, instead of $ gem update system.